Understanding もしかしてとも思ったのだがそこは流石の綾瀬さん
There is one sentence I have trouble understanding. It is from chapter two of 義妹生活 novel. The context is that the narrator 浅村 and 綾瀬 plan to go to school 水星 but it seems like 綾瀬 fear students seeing them together:

その日の朝は当然のように綾瀬さんと一緒に登校などというイベントは発生しなかった。水星に通う同級生だと知り、もしかしてとも思ったのだがそこは流石の綾瀬さん、変に噂になるのもアレだし当分は赤の他人ってことで通していきましょうとドライに提案された。

I am not sure how the bold part fits the rest of the sentence. I think there is something omitted after もしかして and 流石の綾瀬さん could be the contents of the narrator thoughts. If you ask me to rewrite this sentence, I'd go with:

俺は綾瀬さんが水星に通う同級生だと知り、もしかして一緒に登校するとも思ったのだが「そこは流石の綾瀬さん」と思って、「変に噂になるのもアレだし当分は赤の他人ってことで通していきましょう」と綾瀬さんにドライに提案された。
After I learned that Ayase is my schoolmate, I believed that we would commute to the school together but, as expected of Ayase, she suggested to me that we should not go together, saying "変に噂になるのもアレだし当分は赤の他人ってことで通していきましょう."


Isn't he saying he thought it might happen (もしかして) but as expected of 綾瀬 (who is very popular) she might not want to have others see them together, because rumors would spread?

@Saegusa what might it refer to?

Them commuting to school together.

Your interpretation is almost correct, but you don't have to assume と思って after そこは流石の綾瀬さん. While 流石の綾瀬さんだ is the protagonist's impression about Ayase, the narrative part of this story is already from his first-person view, so there is no need add と思って.
そこは流石の綾瀬さん(だ) means "As expected of Ayase", "However, Ayase is Ayase", "This is Ayase, so unsurprisingly, ...", etc. We can rewrite the text as follows:

俺は綾瀬さんが水星に通う同級生だと知り、「もしかして一緒に登校するのか」とも思ったのだ。だがそこは流石の綾瀬さんだ。「変に噂になるのもアレだし当分は赤の他人ってことで通していきましょう」と、俺は綾瀬さんにドライに提案された。


Thank you, it seems like the comma after そこは流石の綾瀬さん is used for apposition, right?

@weeab00 No. This is just a run-on sentence. My revised version shows how you should read that part.
